# Are two database fields ever both in use?

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I have this problem I cannot wrap my head around. It is analogous to this: Suppose I have a table with information about ships; there is a `ship_id` column, and lots of rows about each ship. Now, there are two similar numeric attributes, `attr1` and `attr2`.

Considering one ship at a time, sometimes `attr1` has a single value for all ship rows, and there are several values for `attr2`, e.g. `1, 2, 3, ...`. Sometimes `attr2` has a single value, and `attr1` takes several values. **How do I check if there are ships where both attributes vary??**

Here is a sample table in case that didn't make much sense:

```
ship_id     attr1    attr2 ...
  101         1        10
  101         1        11
  101         1        15
  101         1        20
  ...
  201         5        200
  201         6        200
  201         15       200
  201         20       200
  ...
```

Here, `attr1` never varies for ship 101, and `attr2` never varies for ship 201. I want to find ships for which both attributes can vary.

I wrote the following, and it runs without error but I'm not sure if it's doing what I intend. Grouping + DISTINCT makes my head spin...

```
SELECT ship_id, count(DISTINCT attr1) as c1, count(DISTINCT attr2) as c2 
FROM ships 
GROUP BY ship_id
HAVING c1 > 1 and c2 > 1;
```

Comment: Based on your description of the problem, I think the SQL you posted does exactly what you want.

Comment: @Eric Petroelje I second this.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand correctly, you can use `EXISTS` :

```
SELECT s.*
FROM ships s
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 
              FROM ships s1 
              WHERE s1.ship_id = s.ship_id AND s1.attr1 <> s.attr1 AND s1.attr2 <> s.attr2
             );
```

Comment: Interesting! A self-join, in effect.